# invite friends with php permissions error

Tags: facebook-graph-api, friend, invite

Error occur when i invite friend to a public event. (event with can_invite_friend)
If i get permissions with fql, create event is set to 1.

The error : Application does not have permission for this action

My code :

```
$oFacebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => CLE_PUBLIQUE,
        'secret' => CLE_SECRETE,
        'cookie' => true,
    ));
$user = $oFacebook->getUser();
$userToken = $oFacebook->getAccessToken(); 
$resultinvite = $oFacebook->api
   ("/".$eid . "/invited/" . $sspId, "POST", Array('access_token' => $userToken));
```

Thanks
Robin

Comment: Have you made sure your $userToken actually _is_ a user token?

Comment: Well then check it using the debug tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug Have you had the user login to your app first to get a user access token?

Comment: I invite friend after login and my token in débug respond : 

ID de l’application : 

281933465260281 : SSPEvent

Identifiant utilisateur : 

100001501810886 : Station Son Particulier
Émis : 

1355665499 (Il y a 24 secondes)
Expiration : 

1360849499 (in about 2 months)
Valide : Vrai
Origine : Web
Étendues : create_event create_note friends_events manage_notifications photo_upload publish_actions publish_stream read_stream rsvp_event share_item status_update user_events video_upload

Answer (score 0):

Its really simple, you need the rsvp_event Permission

And remember that you need to attend the event before invite some one.